# Trying to setup an SQL based on relative date

Tags: sql, time-series, hana

```
('PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP_GSTRP_FROM$$',
     '20190901'),
```

Attempting to not use static dates in my SQL query.  I really I just want to look back 2 months from Today... always... Not from a static point in time.  How do I write this in?

GSTRP being the date field

Thanks!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: In standard SQL you can use `current_date - interval '2'  month`

Comment: SAP HANA is where I'm pulling my data... actually, I have no idea what kind of a db that is

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @today DATETIME,
@beginToday datetime
set @today = getdate();

select @beginToday =DATEADD(day,datediff(day,0,@today),0);

select DATEADD(MONTH,-2,@beginToday);
```

---

Forgive my ignorance.... where would I add this in?

SELECT
IEDD as "Actual Finish Date",
IEDZ as "Actual Finish Time",
ISDD as "Actual Start Date",
ISDZ as "Actual Start Time",
AND OTHER COLUMNS......
FROM "SOME TABLE"('PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP_Plant$$','1010'))

DECLARE @today DATETIME,
@beginToday DATETIME
SET @today = GETDATE();

SELECT @beginToday =DATEADD(day,datediff(day,0,@today),0);

SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,-2,@beginToday);